# How do I test Rails block helpers with rSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, helper

In my views I use a helper that takes arbitrary HTML as a block:

```
<% some_block_helper do %>
  Some arbitrary HTML and ERB variables here.
  More HTML here.
<% end %>
```

My helper does a bunch of things to the passed block of HTML before rendering it back to the view (Markdown and other formatting). I would like to know what are the cleanest ways of testing the result of the helper call in rSpec, if any. I've found a few examples that muck about with private methods of ERB but that seems a bit brittle and hard to read.

Answer (score 7):

To add just a bit to what James said, I think something like this should work just fine:

```
describe SomeHelper do
  it 'should do something' do
    helper.some_block_helper { the_block_code }.should XXXX
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For a functional test, write a normal [view spec](http://rspec.info/documentation/rails/writing/views.html) and test the result.
2. To unit test your [helper](http://rspec.info/documentation/rails/writing/helpers.html), pass an arbitrary html input string to it directly.

If there's any other difficulty I'm missing, please comment?

Comment: Since the test is in Ruby and not in a template, it's not clear how to replicate the behavior of putting HTML outside of the ERB tags between `do` and `end`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example that expands on Cameron's answer

```
describe SomeHelper do
  it 'should do something' do
    content = lambda { "blah" }                                
    result  = helper.some_block_helper(&content)

    result.should include("blah")
    result.should XXX
  end
end
```